# there is no row at position 0

Tags: c#

Al ejecutar este codigo me sale que la fila 0 esta vacia o no hay posicion, y no lo esta cual pudiera ser el error

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String cmd = string.Format("Select * from admin where admin_nombre = '{0}' " +
                "and admin_contrasena = '{1}'", txtUser.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim());

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = Utilidades.Ejecutar(cmd);

            string nombre, contrasena;
            nombre = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["admin_nombre"].ToString();
            contrasena = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["admin_contrasena"].ToString();

            if(nombre==txtUser.Text.Trim() && contrasena== txtPassword.Text.Trim())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Iniciaste correctamente");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Este es el codigo para la conexion pero la tengo en una libreria

```
    public static DataSet Ejecutar(string cmd)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Escuela;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas accediando a la row como si siempre fueras a obtener una respuesta de la consulta, pero sino hay coincidencis para los filtros no tendras ninguna row

Tu codigo deberia ser algo como esto

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string query = @"Select * from admin 
                            where admin_nombre = @nombre 
                            and admin_contrasena = @password";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", txtUser.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);

        DataTable dt = Utilidades.Ejecutar(cmd);


        if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Iniciaste correctamente");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Y la ejecucion recibe el command, asi puedes indicar parametros y no concatener en un string los valores

```
public static DataTable Ejecutar(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    string connstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Escuela;Integrated Security=True";
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }

}
```

Como veras:

- Usa siemrpe paramteros, no se concatena los valores en un string
- Usa el SqlCommand para definir estos parametros
- Cuando aplicar un `where` por el nombre y contraseña ya obtienes el registro no necesitas volver a compara los valor es en el if, solo valida si retorno un registro coincidente
- Si solo vas a trabajar una tabla usa el datatable
- Define la conexion dentro de un bloque `using` asi se destruye el objeto de forma correcta

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, lo que me frustra es el hecho de que en otros proyectos lo tengo exactamente igual al que puse y no me deja, no se que puede pasar

Comment: El problema es de datos, si pones un nombre y contraseña que no coincide con ningun registros, no vas a obtener ninguna row, por eso debes validarlo antes de acceder usando `if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0){...` entonces si hay mas de una row recien alli puede acceder al dato

Comment: igual mas alla de esa validacion siempre debes usar parametros, es una pesima practica concatenar los valores en el string